# Virtualenv: "main.py" gives error but "python main.py" works perfectly fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I created a new virtualenv to test fuzzywuzzy. I activate my env and "pip install fuzzywuzzy"

I create a file "main.py" with the following code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

r = fuzz.ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")

print(r)
```

Back to the console, I activate the env and enter "main.py":

```
(fuzzytest) C:\Users\Family\Desktop\fuzzytest>main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Family\Desktop\fuzzytest\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
ImportError: No module named 'fuzzywuzzy'
```

BUT if I do "python main.py":

```
(fuzzytest) C:\Users\Family\Desktop\fuzzytest>python main.py
97
```

It works fine. Why is that? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: is that first block of code literally all that is in the file, or is the first file something like `#!...`.

Comment: That's all the code yes. I'm just testing and trying things out.

Comment: I've also installed the module to this virtualenv only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting the script with `#! /usr/bin/env python`.

This is supposed to work on windows according to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines).

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing anything wrong?

Yes.

1) `pip` installs modules in a specific directory.

2) When you execute your program with `python`, python searches only in certain directories for the modules you import in your program.  You can see which directories those are by looking at the output of:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

One of those directories is the directory that pip uses to install modules.

3) When you try to execute your program without python, then some other directories are searched, and those directories don't contain the fuzzywuzzy module.